# ListView with multiselect

Tags: android, listview

```
   // **Step 1**: setAdapter to your listview.
   listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, GENRES));
   // **Step 2**:  set choice mode for listview .The second line of below code represents which checkbox should be checked.

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setItemChecked(2, true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);



     private static  String[] GENRES = new String[] {
            "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
            "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"
        };

    //**Step 3:** Checked views are returned in SparseBooleanArray, so you might use the below code to get key or values.The below sample are simply displayed selected names in a single String.
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {

    SparseBooleanArray sp=getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

    String str="";
    for(int i=0;i<sp.size();i++)
    {
        str+=GENRES[sp.keyAt(i)]+",";
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

This is working for me.But If i will uncheck listitem how to remove that item from **str**.
str+=GENRES[sp.keyAt(i)]+",";

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Since you only use `getCheckedItemPositions();`, that should work automatically

Comment: No @Tim this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for that.

```
    String selected = ""; 
    int cntChoice = myList.getCount(); 
    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray =myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
     for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++)
    { 
         if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) 
          { 
             selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
          }
     }
```

this is working for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using a ListActivity since you have the call to getListView()

If that's the case you should be using

```
@Override
void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     // Handle SparseBooleanArray stuff.
}
```

Also, just do a Log.d() for your SparseBooleanArray to see if it's returning the correct values or if it's the ListView not updating properly after unchecking.